# Socket closed abruptly during opening handshake: rabbitmq using nodejs connection fail

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq, compose-db

```
Error: Socket closed abruptly during opening handshake
    at TLSSocket.endWhileOpening (/app/node_modules/amqplib/lib/connection.js:258:17)
    at emitNone (events.js:91:20)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:185:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:974:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:80:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)
```

Comment: Refer this https://github.com/squaremo/amqp.node/issues/101

Comment: In my case this was caused by incorrect authentication. The MQ server log said `PLAIN login refused: user 'admin' - invalid credentials`

Comment: For any future users who might be having this issue: make sure the `port` is set to `5672` ( local `amqp` server) and not `15672` (`amqp` web management console).